# Tomcat 8 Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, compiler-errors, java-7, tomcat8

I have installed Tomcat 8.0.26 with jdk1.7.0_60 on a Linux server.
Then I started the server and I tried to access to tomcat manager but I received the following error: 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP.

I tried to access to the JSP tomcat examples but same error...

Here below the exception I'm receiving:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [/webapps/apache-tomcat8-dev/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet<?> to Set<String>

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [/webapps/apache-tomcat8-dev/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
Cannot instantiate the type HashSet<?>

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [/webapps/apache-tomcat8-dev/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/index_jsp.java]
Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token

    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Could you please help me to find the root cause?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You posted "I tried to access to tomcat manager"  but did you really mean to say that you tried to access Tomcat's home page?

Comment: Also if I try to access to http://servername:port/ I get the same error.

Comment: Yes, that is Tomcat's home page. It is strange error. I don't have solution. But I did find similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490487/tomcat-8-cant-compile-jsp-file-on-different-machine

Comment: What happens if you try to access simple "Hello World" JSP? Name the file hello.jsp  keep  it very simple with a simple String and no scriptlet. Put the file in ROOT web app and call with servername:port/hello.jsp   Post result. Also, edit your question. Take out reference to manager. That is confusing.

Comment: What file did you download from Apache?

Comment: I found the root cause!
I removed my custom library and it worked. Probably there is a library that conflicts with the standard tomcat lib...now I have to perform some tests to detect it

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the issue...now I am able to access the manager but I have some issues with the JSP pages. I opened some Tomcat example and Basic Arithmetic and Basic Comparison work. If I try other example..for instance the JSP 1.2 examples they don't work. I get:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [30] in the generated java file: [/webapps/apache-tomcat8-dev/work/Catalina/localhost/examples/org/apache/jsp/jsp/num/numguess_jsp.java]
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet<?> to Set<String>

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, at the end I has still a jar in my lib folder that created conflicts. I removed it and now all is working properly.